# Duvida sintaxe: Como buscar o valor minimo e maximo de um campo em linq com where

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-entities

Preciso criar uma função em `linq` que me retorne os valores mínimos e máximos de um campo de uma lista. Consegui realizar uma consulta SQL dessa forma, mas preciso  disso na sintaxe em `linq`.

```
SELECT
MIN(DATALANCAMENTO),
MAX(DATALANCAMENTO)
FROM CONTACORRENTECOMISSOES
WHERE SEQUENCIALOTELOJISTA = 14 //
```

Tentei realizar desta forma, mas o sistema não permite usar o `.Where`.

```
var dtMin = unit.ContaCorrenteComissoes.Min(c => c.DATALANCAMENTO).Where(c => c.SequenciaLoteLojista == nuLote
var dtMax = unit.ContaCorrenteComissoes.Max(c => c.DATALANCAMENTO).Where(c => c.SequenciaLoteLojista == nuLote)
```

Conseguem ajudar?

Comment: o min não retorna uma lista, por isso você não consegue chamar o where depois, em outras palavras faça o where primeiro, chame o min por último

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você deve usar o Where() depois o Min() ou o Max(), pois ambos (min, max) retornam um valor único e o método Where só se aplica a Listas:

```
var dtMin = unit.ContaCorrenteComissoes.Where(c => c.SequenciaLoteLojista == nuLote).Min(c => c.DATALANCAMENTO);
var dtMax = unit.ContaCorrenteComissoes.Where(c => c.SequenciaLoteLojista == nuLote).Max(c => c.DATALANCAMENTO);
```